# Yum batch install package cause 100% CPU load?

Tags: shell, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I need to install a list of package as follow; so I made a small script automate it:

```
yum -y install libstdc++.i686
yum -y install libibcm.x86_64
yum -y install librdmacm.x86_64
yum -y install ibsim.x86_64
yum -y install ibutils.x86_64
yum -y install libcxgb3.x86_64
yum -y install libibmad.x86_64
yum -y install libipathverbs.x86_64
```

However, it caused a 100% CPU load and hang the system when it started to install dependencies packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you installing one item at a time via a script? No need to do this when you can just place all items in one line like this:

```
yum -y install libstdc++.i686 ibibcm.x86_64 librdmacm.x86_64 ibsim.x86_64 ibutils.x86_64 libcxgb3.x86_64 libibmad.x86_64 libipathverbs.x86_64
```

Now that said, I don’t believe all of the `yum -y install` directives are running simultaneously since I believe `yum` would properly lock the process and wait for the next item. So the CPU usage issue could just be connected to limited system resources such as RAM as well as CPU.

Meaning, if the machine is constrained by limited resources there’s not much you can do to improve the situation. Just sit back and wait for the packages to install. And when that’s done, it’s done so no need to worry about that again.

Comment: Hi, I don't know that `yum` can accept parameters like that :) The system has a e5450 xeon and 8gb of ram so I don't think it lack of resources. I let the system runs overnight and it still stuck there :(

Comment: Put all packages in a big parameter works like a charm! Thank you!